# Kotlin get target of jquery click

Tags: kotlin

If I write the next code I get the compiler error: "Unresolved refrence:target"

```
jq("#element").click {
    console.log(it.target)
}
```

However, if I print only "it" it has the property target

```
r.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: button, currentTarget: button, relatedTarget: null…}
```

How I'm supoused to get the target then?

Comment: I forgot about ts2kt, added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you use `jq` from standard library, and first of all `jq` from standard library is deprecated.

Then lets look at definition of `click` handler:

```
public fun click(handler: (MouseClickEvent) -> Unit): JQuery
```

As you see, `it` in your case is `MouseClickEvent`. But `MouseClickEvent` and `MouseEvent` doesn't contains `target`.

You can write own bindings for jquery:

```
import jquery.MouseClickEvent
import jquery.MouseEvent

@JsName("$")
public external fun jq(selector: String): JQuery

public external class JQuery() {
    public fun click(handler: (ExtendedMouseClickEvent) -> Unit): JQuery
}

public external class ExtendedMouseClickEvent() : MouseEvent {
    public val target: JQuery
    public val which: Int
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    jq("#element").click {
        console.log(it.target)
    }
}
```

Also, you can convert existing definitions for TypeScript to kotlin.

jQuery typings: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery

ts2kt: https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt

Comment: If it's deprecated which is the new way to use JQuery? Cause I found that variable of type JQuery had only a few methods like `.html()` and `.next()` but missing many of the JQuery library

Comment: I described in my answer: took jquery definitions from DefenitelyTyped, use ts2kt to create kotlin interfaces/functions for jquery.

Comment: But this are 3rd party libraries right? If kotlin says jq is deprecated is cause they have implemented a better way in the base kotlin library (with no need of 3rd parties), or am I wrong?

Comment: No, jq in koltin is just bunch of interfaces, actual implementation is jquery, which should be included in your html to work.